# Need to avoid Email Address update verification email sent to the Salesforce Users

Tags: email-alert, user-admin

When we update email address for a User then User receives a verification email alert in new email address and User needs to verify the new email Address then only the new address gets updated (as per the Security in Salesforce)
Even if we update using Apex verification email gets triggered to the User.

For Mass email update we can stop this email alert for a specific period by submitting a case to Salesforce Support with the update Date/time. 
Is there any way we can stop this verification email and update the email address for single User? Trying to check if anyone has gone through 
this before. Thanks for your help in advance.